# Current date in MySQL WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, datetime

I only want the dates starting from the current date. How do I ask this in CodeIgniter?  "end_date" is a DATETIME (Y-m-d H:i:s).

This isn't working:

```
$this->db->select("DATE(end_date) as my_end_date", FALSE);
$this->db->where('my_end_date >', date());
$q = $this->db->get('tblTest');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to format the [date](http://php.net/date) in PHP so that it's in the format MySQL wants.

Try this:

```
$this->db->where('end_date >', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

You can also use MySQL's [`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) for this.

```
$this->db->where('end_date > NOW()', NULL, FALSE);
```

<strike>EDIT: If you want to use the alias `my_end_date`, you can use HAVING instead of WHERE.</strike>

```
$this->db->having('my_end_date > NOW()', NULL, FALSE);
```

Comment: No, didnt work. I always get this error: Error Number: 1054 Unknown column 'new_end_date' in 'where clause'

Comment: @KevinGorjan: You need to use the `end_date` field in the where clause, not its alias.

Comment: $this->db->where("'my_end_date' > NOW()", NULL, FALSE); this one give no errors, but still give me the older dates.

Comment: putting "end_date" in the where doens't work because of the alias.

Comment: @KevinGorjan: It should be: `$this->db->where('end_date > NOW()', NULL, FALSE);`.

Comment: @KevinGorjan: I don't think the alias is the reason it's not working.

Comment: Ok, works perfectly! thanks => right answer is $this->db->where('end_date > NOW()', NULL, FALSE);